# What does 'arranged' modify in this sentence?

Tags: participle-phrases

This is from [a webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrow-body_aircraft) :

> A narrow-body aircraft or single-aisle aircraft is an airliner
> **arranged** along a single aisle, permitting up to 6-abreast seating in a
> cabin less than 4 metres (13 ft) in width.

I think you arrange not airliners but seating so "**arranged**" seems to modify 'seating' in this sentence.

So I think it may be better to rephrase the sentence like this :

*A narrow-body aircraft or single-aisle aircraft is an airliner permitting up to 6-abreast seating **arranged** along a single aisle, in a cabin less than 4 metres (13 ft) in width.*

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the same thing to arrange seating in an airliner or to arrange an airliner in terms of its seating.

Similarly, you can arrange the seats in a room, or arrange a room in terms of its seating.

> ...Wright came to the house before the photo shoot and arranged the room as he wanted it presented in the book...

Source: [The Met](https://Wright%20came%20to%20the%20house%20before%20the%20photo%20shoot%20and%20arranged%20the%20room%20as%20he%20wanted%20it%20presented%20in%20the%20book)

Comment: Thank you very much.